# Is there a way to capture HTTPS traffic using ironpython?

Tags: python, ironpython

I'm trying to capture HTTPS traffic using python/ironpython. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: "Capture" how/where/from what to what?

Comment: On clicking a button in my application, browser is launched with URL. I found options only to validate final URL but not intermediate URL (sorry, I'm not sure how you call it). I'm trying validate parameters in that intermediate URL using python. Can you please help me with that?